# Which has a higher order of growth n(n+1) or 2000n^2?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I think they have the same order of growth because both are `O(n^2)`, correct? And even though `2000n^2` has a higher coefficient, they're both the same complexity since `O(n) < O(n^2) < O(n^3)` is this thinking correct? If not, how can I understand their order of growth better?

Comment: Take a look at the [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57/68251). Specifically for your problem, "order-of-growth", I think big-Theta $\Theta$ notation would be more applicable for comparison. For instance, $n^3$ and $n^4$ are both $O(2^n)$ but that doesn't tell us much about how they compare. If we know $n^3 = \Theta(n^3)$ and $n^4 = \Theta(n^4)$, this tells us much more of how to compare them.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755